# Ajax serialize; Cant 'read' variables in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this code:

```
var data_string = $('form#frm').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type:       "POST",
        url:        "/send.php",
        data:       data_string,
        success:    function(data) {
        alert(data);
```

And in the php file:

```
$to = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);    //email
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);   //name of tipper
$msg = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['msg']);     //message
echo $name; //EXAMPLE
```

The above alert in the ajax code SHOULD alert the posted `$name` variable.
However, the alertbox comes up, but it is blank.

I think it has to do with the serialize part.

echoing 1 or 0 from php works fine, and the alert box shows the 1 or 0.

Any ideas whats wrong?

Thanks

EDIT:

Found out that when alerting the serialized data:

```
 alert (data_string);
```

I get "undefined"...

And here is the form:

```
<form name='frm' id='frm' action='send.php' method='post' onsubmit='tip_func(); return false;'>

<input type='text' name='name' id='name'>
```

tip_func() is the function where all the above ajax is...

Comment: What does the serialized data look like?

Comment: Can you post some example form HTML?

Comment: @Camran - in your form html you need to replace < with &lt; or it doesn't show properly

Comment: @Camran - Do you perform mysql_connect before calling mysql_real_escape_string ?

Comment: I don't understand why the alertbox returns undefined. It doesn't find the form. I am sure the name and all is correct.

Comment: @Camran install the TamperData firefox plugin so that you can see exactly what is being sent to the server with your HTML "POST" operation. Firebug will also show you the HTTP resonse from the ajax call

Comment: @Camran - Is your browser's error log reporting anything when you try submit the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tested the `data_string`? Try doing an alert on it first to check it has data in it!

```
var data_string = $('#frm').serialize();
alert(data_string);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This isn't a solution, this should be a comment added to the question

Answer (score 2):

According to the `.serialize()` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

> Note: Only "successful controls" are
>   serialized to the string. No submit
>   button value is serialized since the
>   form was not submitted using a button.
>   For a form element's value to be
>   included in the serialized string, the
>   element must have a name attribute.
>   Data from file select elements is not
>   serialized.

Did you check all of this? Have you tried alerting `data_string`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to pass data to the javascript function then why not just use `json` (http://json.org/) for this, as it is designed to serialize and there are numerous options for most languages, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Ultimately you can spend time working on how to get serialize to work, but your time may be more productive if you consider making a change.

Answer (score 1):

Seems it works now, I replaced:

```
var data_string = $('form#frm').serialize();
```

With:

```
var form = document.getElementById('frm');
var data_string = form.serialize();
```

Very confusing to me...

Comment: Very strange. Both worked for me when I tested. Well, at least you got it to work!

Answer (score 0):

Try `print_r($_POST)` instead to see if your $_POST vars are posted after all.