# how to decode serialize url from javascript in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

please consider following snippet 
    i have submited a form which contains a background image url , i have serialize the form data . in php the URL is not decoding , how to get orignal url

```
$("#slider_settings_form").submit(function(e) {
    var postData = $(this).serialize();
    submited form
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
            "params": postData,
            "action": "saveFormSettings"
        },
        method: "POST",
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        },

    });
```

Comment: use "decodeURIComponent()"

Comment: what you have try for decode url in php??

Answer (score 1):

Use `string urldecode( string $str )` function to decode your encoded URL data
for more follow this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Answer (score 1):

A successful parsing could be done by adding `urldecode` like this:

```
parse_str(urldecode($_REQUEST['params']), $params);
```

`urldecode` is important because it converts url encoded string into parsable string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve it from javascript you can use these methods:

```
var uri = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587877/how-to-decode-serialize-url-from-javascipt-in-php"
var uri_enc = encodeURIComponent(uri); //for encoding
var uri_dec = decodeURIComponent(uri_enc); //for decoding
```

Here is the link for more details: 
[Url decode and encode](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248073/ajax-serialize-cant-read-variables-in-php?rq=1).

We need to see how you're decoding the data in PHP to help you, but in addition to the answer ahead of mine (suggesting the use of `urldecode`), you should also make sure `postData` actually has data in it.

> Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string [...] - *second answer*

It's entirely possible `postData` is nil. You should test it by alerting it and go from there. The question I linked to has a more thorough answer with code examples.

Answer (score 0):

`var postData = $(this).serialize();` -- this would create a query string like `'a=1&b=2'`, where `a` and `b` are form fields. You might want to fetch the value of `a` or `b` -- the following code will help you:

```
parse_str($_GET['params'], $params);
// then you can use $params['a'] to fetch form field 'a'
print_r($params);
// => 
//Array
//(
//    [a] => 1
//    [b] => 2
//)
```

For more about `parse_str`, see [http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)